# How can I make this daemon/init run as a non root user?

Tags: ubuntu, non-root-user, init-script

I have an init script to kick off a daemon.  The problem is it runs as root.  I would like it to run as a user called "deploy".  Ubuntu 12.04

```
#! /bin/sh

# File: /etc/init.d/unicorn

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn web server
# Description:       starts unicorn
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails
DAEMON_OPTS="-c /var/www/current/config/unicorn.rb -D"
NAME=unicorn
DESC="Unicorn"
PID=/var/www/current/shared/pid/unicorn.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Change `$DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS` to `su - deploy -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS"`

Comment: Beware not to launch the deamon using the "service" command while you are testing since the chuid option will have no effect and the process will run as root.

Comment: Are all scripts in init.d called *after* kernel already knows the users in system ?

Answer (score 24):

Use the [`start-stop-daemon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) utility to start your daemon. Pass the `-c` (or `--chuid`) option to run it as a different user. You'll find some examples in `/etc/init.d/*`.

```
case $1 in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --chuid deploy --pidfile "$PID" --start --exec "$DAEMON" -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
…
```

Comment: Are all init.d scripts called after kernel already knows all users in system ?

Comment: @ransh I'm not sure what you're asking. The kernel does not really “know” users: as far as it's concerned, a user is just a number, and it doesn't care what the number is except that processes running as user 0 can do many things that other users can't.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu you can use just

`sudo -u deploy $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS`

Comment: Why add sudo when su or --chuid exists? What if sudo is not installed?

Comment: @JeffSchaller sudo is installed on Ubuntu